# Symfony2 Sylius setting the default locale

Tags: symfony, sylius

When I want to create a Shipment I get the error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("No locale has been set and current locale is undefined.") in SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig at line 148.
```

I think I need to set the default locale for sylius, but I tried alot of examples, none of them helped..

I currently have this setup:

Config.yml:

```
sylius_shipping:
    driver: doctrine/orm # Configure the Doctrine ORM driver used in documentation.
    classes:
        shipping_method:
            model: Application\Sylius\ShippingBundle\Entity\ShippingMethod
            translation:
                model: Application\Sylius\ShippingBundle\Entity\ShippingMethodTranslation
        shipping_method_rule:
            model: Application\Sylius\ShippingBundle\Entity\Rule
        shipment:
            model: Application\Sylius\ShippingBundle\Entity\Shipment
        shipment_item:
            model: Application\Sylius\ShippingBundle\Entity\ShipmentItem
        shipping_category:
            model: Application\Sylius\ShippingBundle\Entity\ShippingCategory

#stof_doctrine_extensions:
#    orm:
#        default:
#            timestampable: true

parameters:
    sylius.locale: %locale%

#sylius_locale:
#    driver: doctrine/orm

sylius_translation:
    default_locale: "%locale%"



#sylius_translation:
#    default_locale: %sylius.locale%
```

Parameters.yml:

```
sylius.currency_importer.ecb.base_currency: EUR
sylius.currency_importer.open_exchange_rates: EDITME
sylius.locale: en_US
```

Nothing works..

**UPDATE**

By changing my config to this:

```
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: %sylius.locale% }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%sylius.locale%"

parameters:
    sylius.locale: 'en'

#sylius_locale:
#    driver: doctrine/orm

sylius_translation:
    default_locale: %sylius.locale%
```

I still get the same error. I cleared my cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try `%sylius.locale%`. It looks like you've just not put in the full name of the parameter in your config file.

If you've updated the value and it's not working, make sure you clear your cache.

```
$ app/console cache/clear --env=dev
$ app/console cache/clear --env=prod
```

You will also require something like this:

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
```

Otherwise the parameters you enter will not be loaded into the configuration file.

Comment: Not putting this as part of the answer, but you can use this as a reference too: https://github.com/ZKFAdAstra/shop/blob/fbddfa705b618c56dcb8cdddf1d5470b178dd4f1/app/config/config.yml#L16

Comment: If the config you've posted in your question is what you've got now, it's wrong. You're using `%locale%` which doesn't exist, you need to use `%sylius.locale%`.

Comment: I get circullar error: Circular reference detected for parameter "sylius.locale" ("sylius.locale" > "sylius.locale").. P.S I am importing the parameters file

Comment: If you're including the parameter in both your config.yml and parameters.yml then maybe that's the cause, it should only be in one of them.

Comment: @Dominykas55 did you finally found a fix for this?